# CombinedResourceHandler doesnt work with PrimeFaces or PF Extensions

Tags: primefaces, jsf-2.2, omnifaces, primefaces-extensions, combinedresourcehandler

I will begin with an example, if I have 2 panels like this:

```
<h:panelGroup id="container">
  <!-- PANEL 1 -->
  <c:if test=#{bean.render1}>
    <ui:include ... />
  </c:if>

<!-- PANEL 2 -->
  <c:if test=#{bean.render2}>
    <ui:include ... />
  </c:if>
</h:panelGroup>
```

Panel 2 has a "p:fileupload" component, by default panel 1 is showed when the page is loaded, when I change to panel 2 an ajax request is sent to update the "container" but I get an exception due to this code:

```
createWidget : function(widgetConstructor, widgetVar, cfg, resource) { 
  if(PrimeFaces.widget[widgetConstructor]) {
    //...
  } else {
    var scriptURI = $('script[src*="/javax.faces.resource/primefaces.js"]').attr('src').replace('primefaces.js', resource + '/' + resource + '.js'),
        cssURI = $('link[href*="/javax.faces.resource/primefaces.css"]').attr('href').replace('primefaces.css', resource + '/' + resource + '.css'),
        cssResource = '<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="' + cssURI + '" />';
    //...
  }
}
```

How u could guess, some components (When I use c:if or with pe:ckEditor) load additional libraries without use the @ResourceDependency annotation, in that case I'll get an exception because the resource "primefaces.js" doesnt exists, was replaced by omnifaces.

Any suggestion to resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

There are 3 options in order to solve this design problem:

1. Don't use ajax to navigate, instead use a normal (and bookmarkable and SEO friendly) request.
2. Don't use view build time tags for request based rendering (by ajax), instead use the `rendered` attribute.
3. Explicitly include the missing resource yourself using `<h:outputScript>`. E.g. for `<p:fileUpload>`:

   ```
   <h:outputScript library="primefaces" name="fileupload/fileupload.js" target="head" />
   ```

Comment: When I use rendered the response time is high... Could be this due to a Mojarra bug?